# Boost.python error in hello world example

Tags: c++, python, boost

I keep getting the error when I try to compile the hello world example with bjam. Everything in Jamroot file ran ok, except the last line (when I commented this line, no error happens):

```
run-test hello : hello_ext hello.py ;
```

The error is:

```
capture-output bin/hello.test/gcc-4.5.2/debug/hello
export: 3: LD_LIBRARY_PATH: bad variable name

    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/hoangtu/Programs/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.5.2/debug:/home/hoangtu/Programs/boost_1_46_1/libs/python/example/tutorial/bin/gcc-4.5.2/debug:/usr/bin:/usr/lib:/usr/lib32:/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

    PYTHONPATH=bin/gcc-4.5.2/debug
export PYTHONPATH
 "/usr/bin/python2.7" "hello.py"   > "bin/hello.test/gcc-4.5.2/debug/hello.output" 2>&1
    status=$?
    echo >> "bin/hello.test/gcc-4.5.2/debug/hello.output"
    echo EXIT STATUS: $status >> "bin/hello.test/gcc-4.5.2/debug/hello.output"
    if test $status -eq 0 ; then
        cp "bin/hello.test/gcc-4.5.2/debug/hello.output" "bin/hello.test/gcc-4.5.2/debug/hello"
    fi
    verbose=0
    if test $status -ne 0 ; then
        verbose=1
    fi
    if test $verbose -eq 1 ; then
        echo ====== BEGIN OUTPUT ======
        cat "bin/hello.test/gcc-4.5.2/debug/hello.output"
        echo ====== END OUTPUT ======
    fi
    exit $status

...failed capture-output bin/hello.test/gcc-4.5.2/debug/hello...
...failed updating 1 target...
...skipped 1 target...
```

Comment: Have you tried starting `bjam` via 'sh -c bjam` to make sure it's not some shell oddity?

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) include your `bjam` invocation in the above, and 2) increase the debugging level (-d if I recall).

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered similar problem during building adobe asl library. The problem was the version of installed from ubuntu repositories bjam (3.1.16). After installing latest bjam from sourceforge (3.1.18), everything worked as it should.

PS. OS is Ubuntu 11.04